# Leetcode: Count Good Nodes in a Binary tree

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to solve LeetCode problem [1448. Count Good Nodes in Binary Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-good-nodes-in-binary-tree/description/):

> Given a binary tree `root`, a node *X* in the tree is named **good** if in the path from root to *X* there are no nodes with a value *greater than* X.
>
> Return the number of **good** nodes in the binary tree.

This was my solution:

```java
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public int goodNodes(TreeNode root) {
        int ans = dfs(root);
        return ans;
    }

    int maxL = 0;
    int maxR = 0;
    int countL = 0;
    int countR = 0;

    private int dfs(TreeNode root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int valL = dfs(root.left);
        if (valL > root.val) {
            countL++;
        }
        else {
            if(root.val > maxL) {
                countL = 0;
                maxL = root.val;
            }
            else{
                countL = countL;
            }
        }
    
        int valR = dfs(root.right);
        if (valR > root.val) {
            countR++;
        }
        else {
            if (root.val > maxR) {
                countR = 0;
                maxR = root.val;
            }
            else {
                countL = countL;
            }
        }

        return countR + countL;
    }       
}
```

The solution I wrote for it seems correct to me logically. It's giving me output 0 for all test cases.

I'm not sure why. Is it because I'm initialising the four variables outside it as 0 and that's the value it holds on to when called from the method `goodNodes`? I'd really appreciate if someone could point out the exact error in my logic here.

I set the count to 0 whenever I encounter a node whose `maxL` or `maxR` is less than it because it means that all the nodes before the current node cannot be counted as good nodes if the max node itself is being exceeded in value by this current node.

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

- although `dfs` returns a *count*, you compare that count with a *node value*, in the expression `valL> root.val`: this is comparing things that have nothing to do with each other.
- `maxL` is never decreased, but only increases, yet if you are on a different path than where that maximum was found, it should be no longer relevant. Instead of using a field for this, use a local parameter, so that when you come back from recursion this maximum is back to what is was before the recursive call was made.

The correction is to not use instance variables for this purpose, but use an extra parameter to `dfs` which represents the maximum on the path to the current node. The function should return the sum of the counts from the recursive calls and add 1 to that if the current node is a good node too:

```java
class Solution {
    public int goodNodes(TreeNode root) {
        return dfs(root, root.val);
    }

    private int dfs(TreeNode root, int maxOnPath) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        int count = root.val >= maxOnPath ? 1 : 0;
        maxOnPath = Math.max(root.val, maxOnPath);
        return count + dfs(root.left, maxOnPath) + dfs(root.right, maxOnPath);
    }    
}
```